# I need faster SQL query to find expired subscribers

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables in MySQL members and subscribers. What I want to do is; I would like to find subscribers who has at least 1 expired subscription and no active subscription.

```
SELECT mem.id as id 

FROM members as mem 
INNER JOIN subscriptions as sub ON sub.member_id = mem.id 

WHERE 
sub.active = 0 AND 
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM subscriptions as sub2 WHERE sub2.member_id = mem.id AND sub2.active = 1 )

Group By mem.id
```

This query takes too long to process (considering the amount of the records 2 tables holds, it is normal).

I waited around 2 minutes to see the results but since it was still trying to load, I just cancelled it. I need results faster. Is there any other way to do this?

Thank you for your time and concern.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what 'expired' means.  Which fields indicate an expired subscription?

Comment: do you have some indexes? what `EXPLAIN select ...` returns?

Comment: It's just a join optimization problem. Try selecting only the records in sub that are active and get the exclusion set from the original table. The join is unnecessary. I say this because having done updates on considerable sized postgre tables, it makes a difference.

Comment: expired means subscription is not valid anymore.Let's say a members subscription is valid till May so while searching during the April if the same member didn't subscribe during April, this member is not an active subscriber anymore.

I didn't want to create indexes. This part of the system will not be used so often so I didn't want to increase the size of the database.

Comment: @Revenant - so basically, active = 0 means expired. Gotcha.  You should at minimum create primary keys and have an index on the column 'active'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  (make sure you have proper indexes).  Also note that I left in the original join because I'm assuming you're going to want more than just member_id at some point.  But if all you want is member_id, you could remove the members table all together.

```
/*
insert members (member_name) values ('tom')
insert members (member_name) values ('bob')
insert members (member_name) values ('jim')

declare @tom int
set @tom = (select member_id from members where member_name = 'tom')

insert subscriptions (member_id, is_active) values (@tom, 1)
insert subscriptions (member_id, is_active) values (@tom, 0)

declare @bob int
set @bob = (select member_id from members where member_name = 'bob')

insert subscriptions (member_id, is_active) values (@bob, 0)
insert subscriptions (member_id, is_active) values (@bob, 0)
*/

SELECT m.member_id
FROM members as m 
INNER JOIN subscriptions as s ON s.member_id = m.member_id 
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s2 on s2.member_id = m.member_id and s2.is_active = 1
WHERE 
s.is_active = 0 and
s2.subscription_id is null

Group By m.member_id
```

OR

```
SELECT s.member_id
FROM subscriptions as s
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s2 on s2.member_id = s.member_id and s2.is_active = 1
WHERE 
s.is_active = 0 and
s2.subscription_id is null

Group By s.member_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had to create a new table to store indexes. Anyway around it takes ages to load the data. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Revenant - Welcome!  And just to clarify, NOT EXISTS with a subquery is what was slowing you down. Basically it is converted to (x <> a or x <> b or x <> c or ... or x <> n). One OR condition for each record in the subquery for each record in the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

I can't guess why you are doing your sql like  this  but this might work

```
SELECT mem.id as id 
FROM members as mem 
INNER JOIN subscriptions as sub ON sub.member_id = mem.id 
WHERE sub.active = 0 
Group By mem.id
```

Update : I guess you might add `deactivted_date` column or something to indicate expiration

Comment: This wouldn't work. If the same member also has 1 active subscription and 1 expired subscription with your query same member would be listed in active subscribers and expired subscribers.

Comment: Why are you repeating the inner join cond in the where clause 'AND  sub.member_id = mem.id' ?

Comment: @tawfekov - The solution still does not address the fact that one subscriber could have multiple subscriptions, with 1 or more being active.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT and group by should perform the same, but i find the query more readable with DISTINCT.

An index on active will probably speed the query up.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mem.id as id
FROM members as mem, subscriptions as sub WHERE sub.member_id = mem.id AND 
sub.active = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM subscriptions as sub2
   WHERE sub2.member_id = mem.id AND sub2.active = 1
)
```